# How do I update my delegate with a new location every time it's moved more than 50 metres?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

So I need my delegate updated with a new location when ever the device has moved 50 metres or more. This is part of an end of chapter quiz in a book I'm learning with.

**Here is my code:**

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder //we're overriding the superclasses (UIViewController) initialiser
{

    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self){
        //create location manager object
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

        //there will be a warning from this line of code
        [locationManager setDelegate:self];

        //and we want it to be as accurate as possible
        //regardless of how much time/power it takes
        [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];

        //set the amount of metres travelled before location update is made
        [locationManager setDistanceFilter:50];

        //tell our manager to start looking for its location immediately
        [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

    }

    return self;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [locations lastObject]);
}
```

I have set the distance filter to 50 (I hope that corresponds to 50 metres). Then when printing to console I've called the last object in the array which I hope would be the most recently updated location.

I then build and run and the initial location is printed to console. I then click `debug > location > city run` in my iOS simulator menu. I guess this takes the location passt 50 metres as a city run would definitely be more than 50 metres. The location is updated again. I try to update the location again by clicking freeway drive and nothing happens.

In the docs it states:  "*It does not rely on the value in the distanceFilter property to generate events. Calling this method several times in succession does not automatically result in new events being generated*"

This is exactly what I'm experiencing. I can change location once and have the new location printed to console.. however changing the location again results in no changes.

I thought the `-locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` updates console with the new location every time it's updated. Do I need to do this some other way?

Hope you can help
Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call: `startUpdatingLocation` like this:

```
if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Comment: I had that originally and that updated my delegate automatically every second or so. I now only want to update on location change so i replaced that with startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges

Comment: If you have something like `self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 10.0f;` your delegate method should only get called every 10 meters. Maybe it's something with the simulator

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise every time it's getting called is simulating metres moved. I've tested it with both 50 and 10 and it works as expected. i also removed the startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges. I thought that I was suppose to some how make the ios simulator act like it had moved 50 metres or more.